# Contour plot from dataframe containing date and 2 values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hej

Im corrently working with some data, where oxygen is a function of depth and time. I'v like to make a contour plot, where the `y = depth` , `x = index(months)` and `z = oxygen concentrations`. But running the script below, the `zaxis` illustrats depth, `yaxis` is emty. The figure i get, is not what i want, but cant figure out what im during wrong.

The plotting part of the script.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = ilt.index.values
y = ilt.columns.values
z = ilt.values.T
CS = ax.contourf(x, y, z, 40, cmap="jet")
ax.set(xlabel="Date", ylabel='Dybde' )
```

ilt = df
[Pic of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot6le.png)

[This is how iv like the plot to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfts0.png)

Comment: can you provide some of your data?

Comment: please, for the future, have a look in here [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).